# How to import .obj files into Maya 2011?

Tags: 3d, maya

I'm using [123D](http://123dapp.com) (a great 3D suite from Autodesk) that generates `.obj` files.
I'm trying to open them in Maya 2011, but to no avail.
It's strange because both applications are from Autodesk, yet they don't use compatible file formats. (That goes for 3D studio as well)
Any ideas?

I've read many google results and forum threads, but still got no clue on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Autodesk FBX. 
Its almost like the "Bridge" in Adobe Suites.

It lets you interchange files from various Autodesk products.

I believe there is some loss by opening them in Maya. I think you would just have to go to File > import, to do so. 
But if that doesnt work, I think your best bet is Autodesk FBX. 
Plus I think its free to download. Give it a shot bud.

One thing I do know that you lose when opening them in Autodesk, is the texture. So if you have any textures applied to the .obj, then you should most definitely look into FBX, because I am pretty sure it will prevent any loss.

Hope that works man, im not the best with 3D rendering software. (But I do have autodesk. ;))

Comment: That's right, Maya doesn't get the texture from the `.obj`. I tried with `.fbx` and works great. But the thing is a job that I made before, and it's only in Autodesk's site, and the only file it offers is the `.obj` so I guess it's lost forever.